# Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup. in flutter with google drive

Tags: flutter, google-drive-api, flutter-getx

When I am trying to fetch data from google drive then I am getting these issues.

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: DetailedApiRequestError(status: 403, message: Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.)

Fetching Code:

```
    var client = http.Client();
    var drive = ga.DriveApi(client);
    drive.files.list(spaces: 'gdrv').then((value) {
      print('Value = ${value}');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

> Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.

Is the error message you get when you have not sent an authorization header with your request.

Requests to the Google drive api access private user data which means you need to be authenticated in order to access that data.

Your http client appears to be missing all the headers I found this example [How to Use the Google Drive API With Flutter Apps](https://betterprogramming.pub/the-minimum-guide-for-using-google-drive-api-with-flutter-9207e4cb05ba) it may help.

```
class GoogleAuthClient extends http.BaseClient {
  final Map<String, String> _headers;

  final http.Client _client = new http.Client();

  GoogleAuthClient(this._headers);

  Future<http.StreamedResponse> send(http.BaseRequest request) {
    return _client.send(request..headers.addAll(_headers));
  }
}
```